# custom expression to subtract from and then multiply the sum of a column in spotfire

Tags: expression, spotfire

What would the custom expression for: **2*(Max[X] - 0.5)** for every group be, in Spotfire?
Do I need to split this into multiple steps or can create a custom expression that would do it all at once for every group of data I have.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I did it in two steps:
1. Created a calculated column Max_X = Max([X]) OVER [GROUP]
2. Created a calculated column D = 2*([Max_X] -0.5)